# What is the difference between inserting segments before and after the floating body?

Tags: pdftex

Generally, a floating body is inserted between two paragraphs. We will insert `\par` above and below the floating body, but one `\par` can be segmented. I found that if only the `\par` is inserted in front of the floating body, the typesetting effect is good, but if only the `\par` is inserted behind the floating body, the typesetting effect is bad, and extra vertical spacing will be generated between the two paragraphs. What is the difference between inserting `\par` above and below the floating body to segment, and why different typesetting effects are produced.

In the following way, extra vertical distance will be generated between two sections.

```latex
This is the first paragraph. This is the first paragraph. This is the first paragraph. This is the first paragraph.
\begin{figure}
\centering
\input{1.pgf}
\caption{fig1}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}
\par
This is the second paragraph. This is the second paragraph. This is the second paragraph. This is the second paragraph.
```

In this way, the distance between the two paragraphs is normal.

```latex
This is the first paragraph. This is the first paragraph. This is the first paragraph. This is the first paragraph.
\par
\begin{figure}
\centering
\input{2.pgf}
\caption{fig2}
\label{fig2}
\end{figure}
This is the second paragraph. This is the second paragraph. This is the second paragraph. This is the second paragraph.
```

Because the sample code is too short, the above two sample codes may not be reproduced.

Comment: not necessarily between paragraphs and it is rather unusual to use a literal `\par` command in a document you normally use a blank line. It would be easier to answer your question if you provided a test file that shows the effect that you are asking about, the floats could appear in any position just given those fragments.

Comment: I provided a test document in my answer, but it shows equal spacing, If you modify it to show the spacing that you are asking about, add the modified version to your question and I will update my answer to explain any space differences that you see.

Comment: ah, I thought of one case, I will extend my aswer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paragraph spacing for the two forms that you show would be expected to be the same, see this example with  blank line (`\par`) before the first figure and after the second figure.

Note however the spaces are stretchy so you may get different space between paragraphs on different pages.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}

This is the first paragraph. This is the first paragraph. This is the first paragraph. This is the first paragraph.

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{2cm}{3cm}
\caption{fig1}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}
This is the second paragraph. This is the second paragraph. This is the second paragraph. This is the second paragraph.

This is the first paragraph. This is the first paragraph. This is the first paragraph. This is the first paragraph.
\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{2cm}{3cm}
\caption{fig2}
\label{fig2}
\end{figure}

This is the second paragraph. This is the second paragraph. This is the second paragraph. This is the second paragraph.
\end{document}
```

If however the final line before the float is full length, you need to be careful about a final space ending on a line on its own if you do not put a paragraph end before the float:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}

This is the first paragraph. This is the first paragraph. This is the first paragraph. This is the first paragraph.
This is the first paragraph. This is the first...

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{2cm}{3cm}
\caption{fig1}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}
This is the second paragraph. This is the second paragraph. This is the second paragraph. This is the second paragraph.

This is the first paragraph. This is the first paragraph. This is the first paragraph. This is the first paragraph.
This is the first paragraph. This is the first...
\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{2cm}{3cm}
\caption{fig2}
\label{fig2}
\end{figure}

This is the second paragraph. This is the second paragraph. This is the second paragraph. This is the second paragraph.
\end{document}
```

The space generated around figure 2 here could be avoided by adding the paragraph end before the figure or commenting out the end of line, I show with a `%` here.:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}

This is the first paragraph. This is the first paragraph. This is the first paragraph. This is the first paragraph.
This is the first paragraph. This is the first...

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{2cm}{3cm}
\caption{fig1}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}
This is the second paragraph. This is the second paragraph. This is the second paragraph. This is the second paragraph.

This is the first paragraph. This is the first paragraph. This is the first paragraph. This is the first paragraph.
This is the first paragraph. This is the first...%
\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{2cm}{3cm}
\caption{fig2}
\label{fig2}
\end{figure}

This is the second paragraph. This is the second paragraph. This is the second paragraph. This is the second paragraph.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem is really caused by the full width of the text in front of the floating body. I can solve the problem by inserting `%` at the end of that paragraph. However, I am used to using the method of Figure 2, that is, inserting a segment after the floating body. Is there an automatic way to solve this problem without me checking whether the paragraph is full width and inserting `%`?

Comment: @Clara why check? you can always add the `%` or always add a blank line. Was your original example text full width? Very non standard page size?

Comment: It is an IEEE template, and a paragraph just in front of the floating body is full width. I'm curious about why it's designed like this. If it's full width, it will cause such a problem.

Comment: you get the same if you end a paragraph with ` abc {}`  the `figure` is acting like `{}` so you get two spaces at the end (one before the `{}` and one from the end of line. TeX only removes one space so you havean end-of word space at the end of the paragraph, normally that is harmless but if the line is nearly full you can get a line break and the final line of the paragraph (it is not vertical space) is all white and only has the word space and `\parfillskip`,

Comment: But what I meant is, did you check that the "example code" that you posted actually generated the problem you were asking about (as a hint for next time) @Clara

Comment: Since my paper has not been published yet, I used other texts as sample codes. What you said is really the problem I encountered. It is true that the last paragraph of the floating body is full width. Whether I delete a word or finally add `%` can solve this problem. I also have a general understanding of the reasons you said. Is there some kind of macro package to handle this matter automatically, without requiring me to add `%` manually? I know I can segment in front of the floating body, which will avoid this problem, but I don't want to do this.

Comment: What I do now is that if a paragraph is followed by a floating body, then I manually add a `%` at the end of this paragraph to avoid blank lines in PDF.